# How to add colour when send data from google sheets to google calendar

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api, google-workspace

I have the following script that I'm using to send data from google sheets to google calendar so that it creates events in google calendar, but I now need to colour code based on a user selection.

In the worksheet (screen shot below) column "e" will have the colour (or colour code) selected. Is there a way to add to my current script so that colour is added to each event based on the selection in column 'e'?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uf3Yrp11Hq8BfManKgH3BX7VprnaYSolr0d3ZsL_nUM/edit#gid=0

[image]

```
function create_Events() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Timesheet");
  var vs = sh.getRange("A1:E" + sh.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("John@email");
  vs.forEach(([t, s, e, d]) => {
    cal.createEvent(t, new Date(s), new Date(e), { description: d});
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- From your showing sample Spreadsheet, unfortunately, I think that the hex color cannot be directly used for setting the event color. In this case, please use [Enum EventColor](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/event-color).
- In order to retrieve the values from the column "E", please modify `vs.forEach(([t, s, e, d]) => {` to `vs.forEach(([t, s, e, d, color]) => {`. By this, `color` can be used as the value from column "E".

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

**Before you use this script, please modify the values of column "E" from the hex values to [Enum EventColor](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/event-color). It's like `PALE_BLUE`, `PALE_GREEN`, `MAUVE`, and so on.** By this, using the retrieved value and `setColor(CalendarApp.EventColor[color.toUpperCase()])`, the event color is set to the created event.

```js
function create_Events() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Timesheet");
  var vs = sh.getRange("A1:E" + sh.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("hugh@crichtontax.com.au");
  vs.forEach(([t, s, e, d, color]) => {
    cal.createEvent(t, new Date(s), new Date(e), { description: d }).setColor(CalendarApp.EventColor[color.toUpperCase()]);
  });
}
```

#### Note:

- When an error like `Exception: Invalid argument: color` occurs, please check the values of the column "E" again.

#### References:

- [setColor(color)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#setcolorcolor)
- [Enum EventColor](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/event-color)

Comment: thank you for your help, I've changed the value to 
PALE_BLUE as suggested, but I'm still getting errors Exception: Invalid argument: color - any suggestions?

Comment: @RoosterMagic22 Thank you for replying. About `I've changed the value to PALE_BLUE as suggested, but I'm still getting errors Exception: Invalid argument: color - any suggestions?`, as I have already mentioned in my answer, it is considered that the reason for your current issue is due to the invalid values at the column "O". So, in order to confirm this, can you provide your sample Spreadsheet for correctly replicating your current issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Hi Tanika, absolutely - I've added the example worksheet - let me know what you think

Comment: @RoosterMagic22 Thank you for replying. About `Hi Tanika, absolutely - I've added the example worksheet - let me know what you think`, unfortunately, I cannot know the columns and rows from your showing image. So, I asked about the sample Spreadsheet. I apologize for this. For example, what is the row number at "Break" of title? For example, the row number is 5, please modify `"A1:E"` to `"A5:E"` and test it again.

Comment: I've just edited the question with a link to a test worksheet - can you let me know if that works for you? Sorry it tool me longer to put up then I thought.

Comment: @RoosterMagic22 Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I couldn't open it. I apologize for it.

Comment: Bugger - I've added a better image - does that help?

Comment: @oosterMagic22 Thank you for replying and adding more information. From your additional information, I understood that your datarange was changed from your initial situation. In this case, please modify `var vs = sh.getRange("A1:E" + sh.getLastRow()).getValues();` to `var vs = sh.getRange("A8:E" + sh.getLastRow()).getValues();` and test it again. If this was not the direct solution of your current issue, I would like to confirm your sample Spreadsheet.

Comment: Yep Perfect - great job - thankyou, I see my error now. I didn't adjust the range - silly me - thankyou for your help!

Comment: @RoosterMagic22 Thank you for replying and testing it, again. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.